# C++ project performance boost by running another project in the background?

Tags: c++, cpu-usage

I'm trying to boost the performance of my C++ facial tracking algorithm by optimizing the most time-consuming sections of my code. Interestingly, 86% of the entire tracking processing time is consumed by its feature extraction section. That feature extractor takes an image as input and returns the feature vector as output. I isolated the feature extractor from the tracker into a separate project to write an optimized version from scratch and made sure the input and output format and containers are the same as the ones used in the original tracker. Here's the breakdown of the resulting process time.

- Original one                 `3 ms/frame`
- Optimized version          `1 ms/frame`

As can be seen it's supposed to be 3 times faster. But when I insert the new feature extractor into my tracker, inside the tracker it runs at about `2.5 ms/frame`. I can't understand why it gets slower inside the tracker as opposed to when it runs as a standalone project?

But here's the catch that I discovered by accident. If I run the tracker and at the same time I run another project in the background, all of a sudden, the feature extractor inside the tracker would converge to `1 ms/frame`. But as soon as I stop the background project it goes back to `2.5 ms/frame`. This happens both on my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 and on my Desktop PC with Windows 10.

In an attempt to understand this sort of behavior I used my Ubuntu System Monitor and noticed the following regarding all the 8 CPU cores.

- When I run the feature extractor alone 7 cores are engaged by about 5% and one of the cores is engaged by 100%.

[image]

- When I insert the feature extractor in the tracker and run the tracker, all the 8 cores are engaged by about 30%.

[image]

- Now when I run the tracker and along with the tracker I run any other program (let's say the standalone feature extractor), out of all the cores that are engaged by 30%, one jumps up to 100% engagement which may explain the performance boost I get in the tracker as a result.

[image]

The evidence suggests that in order for the feature extractor to run at its maximum potential of `1 ms/frame`, at least one of the cores should be engaged by 100%. My question is how can I make this happen?

Comment: If you're okay with cargo-cult programming, you can spawn off a thread with a `while(1) {}` loop in it, and that will cause a core to spin at 100% CPU usage.  However, it's unlikely that is the best solution -- a better approach would be to study the problem further and not try to come up with a solution until after you're pretty sure you understand *why* the observed behavior is happening.  Without understanding the mechanisms that underly the problem, any proposed solution is likely to be incorrect.

Comment: Is your code running on a different thread already?  If not, it would make sense why putting them together in the same program would slow it down.

Comment: Are you running on a system that automatically downclocks when not under load? Laptops are usually configured to do this automatically, and desktops are set that way on occasion. It's possible pathological workload detection might downcycle just as you're entering a CPU intensive portion of the code.

Comment: What @ShadowRanger said happened to me on an embedded Linux system. I suggest you to search for /sys/class subfolders or something like that, where you could find some hardware configuration on the cpu. I put something like `while true; do cat /sys/class/cpu/cpu0/actual_clock; sleep 1; done` to monitor the current CPU speed. There was also some way to tell it to go to performance mode (fast).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Infinite loops with no observable actions in them are [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub#Infinite_loop_without_side-effects).

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thanks your reply. Your solution actually worked haha (I can't stop smiling). That was pretty smart don't know why it didn't cross my mind. Even though it didn't enable me to find the root cause but it fully engages one of the cores and the process time converges to `1 ms/frame` :)  For now I will keep this in place but you're right, I will also keep studying until I find the right solution.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thanks for your comment. Yes everything runs on a single thread. But I previously tried two other solutions. 1) running the feature extractor on a separate thread and wait for it to join 2) running the tracker and the feature extractor on two different projects and communicate between the two by socket programming. Unfortunately neither of those solution worked.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure if my system automatically downclocks when processing a cpu intensive piece of code. But that's one possibility.

Comment: @Mirko Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I can't rely on any hardware-related solution as it won't be ideal to ask anyone who would use my code to configure their systems accordingly.